# Catch event in asp.net code behind when java-script drop event occur?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, razor

Let say i have a div (on top of aspx file) in which i dragging and dropping elements (another divs or images) via javascript or jQuery. What i would like to achieve is to  be able to catch  drop event in code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call an action on your controller in the [drop event](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/).

You can use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for that like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: yourUrl,
  data: dataSerializedAsJson,
  success: function() { /* action */ },
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: Was this useful to you or do you need more help?